# Resources to learn how to create a compiler /interpreter for the .NET framework

Tags: compiler-construction, dynamic-language-runtime

I'd like to learn more how to create a language for .NET framework.  I think I'd like to build a DLR language.  I'm having hard time founding good resources.  I found [a descent article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136756.aspx) that was written more than a year ago.  I also spent couple of hours looking at IronPython source code.

Could you please share with your resources on this subject.

Thanks

Comment: The authoritative SO question on compiler resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler . Of course you need to understand you target (.NET) too.

Comment: and look, in the first answer to the above "Roll Your Own Compiler for the .NET framework": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136756.aspx

Comment: @dmckee, I read the article and I mentioned it in my question. However, the link to the article in my question is not very descriptive.  You need to click on it to see what article it reefers.  I should've done a better job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the links compiled on this blog.

http://benjaminnitschke.com/post/2009/03/31/Writing-your-own-programming-language-with-the-DLR-%28Dynamic-Language-Runtime%29.aspx

Comment: fixed link: http://benjaminnitschke.com/post/2009/03/31/Writing-your-own-programming-language-with-the-DLR-%28Dynamic-Language-Runtime%29.aspx

Comment: Both urls are down now

Comment: New fixed link: http://benjaminnitschke.com/post/2009/03/30/Writing-your-own-programming-language-with-the-DLR-(Dynamic-Language-Runtime)